# How to add H1 Tag on Homepage?

Tags: customization, custom-field

I am using child theme of rehub theme to create a website. Just like many other themes it has option of "static homepage" and "recent posts" homepage. As my theme is a deal based theme I have to use "recent posts" options.

But, due to this the home page is missing H1 tag because there is no tag by default in the theme. I have no experience of php coding, so please help me in adding H1 tag on the homepage. The site link is - www.top20deals.com

Code of header.php from main rehub theme is as follows -

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<!-- feeds & pingback -->
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->    
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<?php if(rehub_option('rehub_custom_css')) : ?><style><?php echo rehub_option('rehub_custom_css'); ?></style><?php endif; ?>
</head>
```

Comment: What do you want H1 tag to be? This also might be a little not trivial for dynamic data if theme is doing anything "creative" with front page.

Comment: For H1 Tag - "Top Shopping & Travel Deals". While checking SEO, I found out that it is must for google, bing and other search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For H1 Tag - "Top Shopping & Travel Deals".

Since you just want it static just adding `<h1>Top Shopping & Travel Deals</h1>` to a template is not hard.

The likely hard part is determining *which* template is right place for it. You can consult with [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and check which templates theme has and which of them you would need to override in your child theme to get a proper result. You might need to create a *new* template, based on existing one to target necessary context precisely.

Comment: Thanks for the information. As you mentioned <h1>Top Shopping & Travel Deals</h1> can be added to template. So, it should be added to header section only or it can be added to index.php as well?

I checked template hierarchy and found that index.php could be the home page file in child theme.

Comment: It highly depends on your theme. `index.php` is usually too general to add it since _other_ contexts (not home page) might be using it.

Comment: In child theme index.php is mentioned as Main Index Template. But, it does not have head tags in it. So, I am very confused. And, if I try to reach template support, it will take minimum 2-3 days. There is no other main file in child theme, others are admin.php, archives, category, search and single post only. What should I do to find out? Any suggestion?

Comment: There is no universal answer for this. I can't just guess and tell you how your theme works, that's what support is generally for. If you are not comfortable troubleshooting through related code then support probably _is_ your best option to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Whats about this in your Index.php:

```
<?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
        <h1>YOUR TEXT</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```